# different username for commit and github interaction

Tags: github

i have set git.username in my local and global config to xxx. In my commit as well I see author is xxx. However, when i push it to remote repository, it appears different username yyy in the commit. My github username is set to xxx through settings.
I tried to grep "yyy" on my local machine and cannot seem to find it anywhere. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `user.name` option that you set for Git commit authorship isn't a username at all. It is just a *plain old name.* (Most people will likely use their real name or something similar.)

So when GitHub wants to display a username, it doesn't look at the author's name at all. It only looks at the author's **email address** and finds the corresponding GitHub account whose profile has that address.

(You can manage the addresses associated with your GitHub at [Settings → Emails](https://github.com/settings/emails).)